# groovy regex test failing

Tags: regex, grails, groovy

In my Grails 1.3.6 app I've written this class

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils

/**
 * Implementation that converts a name such as <tt>FOO_BAR</tt> to <tt>fooBar</tt>
 */
@Singleton
class CamelCaseEnumTransformer implements EnumTransformer {

    String transformName(Enum e) {

        String transformedName = e.name().toLowerCase()

        transformedName.replaceAll(/_([a-z])/) {
            it[1].toUpperCase()
        }
        StringUtils.remove(transformedName, '_')
    }
}
```

I've created this test case:

```
class EnumTransformerTests extends GroovyTestCase {

    private static enum TestEnum {
        A, FOO, FOO_BAR, FOO_BAR_123,
    }

    void testCamelCaseTransformer() {
        EnumTransformer transformer = CamelCaseEnumTransformer.instance
        assertEquals 'a', transformer.transformName(TestEnum.A)
        assertEquals 'foo', transformer.transformName(TestEnum.FOO)

        // This test fails on the line below
        assertEquals 'fooBar', transformer.transformName(TestEnum.FOO_BAR)
    }
}
```

The test fails on the line marked above. I reckon the problem must be related to the `replaceAll` method, because this is the first time that the closure passed as the second argument to this method is executed.

The error I get is:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: 
CamelCaseEnumTransformer$_transformName_closure1.doCall() 
is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [_b, b]
```

What's particularly strange, is that if I run the equivalent code below in the Groovy console, everything seems to work fine.

```
@Singleton
class CamelCaseEnumTransformer {

    String transformName(Enum e) {

        String transformedName = e.name().toLowerCase()

        transformedName.replaceAll(/_([a-z])/) {
            it[1].toUpperCase()
        }
    }
}

enum TestEnum {
    A, FOO, FOO_BAR, FOO_BAR_123,
}

def transformer = CamelCaseEnumTransformer.instance
assert 'fooBar' == transformer.transformName(TestEnum.FOO_BAR)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message text, it looks like the closure should accept 2 arguments for the 2 matches in your regex. Try the following:

```
    transformedName.replaceAll(/_([a-z])/) { wholeMatch, capturedGroups ->
        capturedGroups[0].toUpperCase();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the lack of a formal means of documenting how many arguments a closure requires is a bit of a pain point for Groovy

Comment: That's the price you pay to get a dynamic language.  I'm pretty sure that you would need a 3 parameter closure if you had 3 matching groups in your regex.

Comment: That's not the case. The second closure argument is a `List` that contains all the captured groups. I edited your code to reflect this.

Comment: @Don: Thank you... I haven't used this particular method yet, I was just guessing based on the error message you saw.